Loading huge number of data files into tables in PostgreSQL
I am creating a database using PostgreSQL where I'm storing data coming from .txt files.
Here is the situation: I have 19 different sources (I call them scenarios), each scenario has two distinct state (I call them categories), so 38 different sources (scenario-category) containing different .txt files containing data in the following format:
Date         Id_1   Id_2    Id_3   Id_4    Id_5   Id_6  Id_7      
---------------------------------------------------------------
"01/01/2006" 0.9769 0.7730  1.9524 0.5831  3.489  598.3 0.4691  
"02/01/2006" 1.3631 0.9308  2.3897 0.5989  4.479  566.1 0.4727  
"03/01/2006" 1.7644 1.0639  3.3321 0.7387  5.545  547.6 0.6055  
"04/01/2006" 1.3637 0.8740  2.8223 0.4926  4.670  517.6 0.4298  
"05/01/2006" 0.9011 0.6898  1.8587 0.3751  3.268  485.8 0.3292  
"06/01/2006" 0.6890 0.5966  1.3966 0.3225  2.568  494.3 0.2813  
"07/01/2006" 0.5710 0.5395  1.1457 0.2982  2.179  550.9 0.2575  
"08/01/2006" 0.4972 0.5000  0.9920 0.2861  1.934  602.8 0.2447  
"09/01/2006" 0.4474 0.4704  0.8893 0.2794  1.766  605.7 0.2371  
"10/01/2006" 1.2444 0.8804  2.0466 0.5396  3.986  567.9 0.4376  
"11/01/2006" 2.0569 1.3623  3.8678 0.9508  6.800  522.5 0.8141 

As you can see the first line is the header with the first column being date and the rest are IDs. What you are seeing here is just a small excerpt of the data file, the number of columns goes up to 1102 and the number of lines can reach thousands (e.g. 40000).
The format of the data files remain the same but the physical meaning of the data is different for different files, some files represent temperature, some represent outflow, etc.
The following is the way I created my tables
-- Create the scenarios table
CREATE TABLE scenarios 
(
    scenario_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    scenario_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Create the categories table
CREATE TABLE categories 
(
    category_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the data table
CREATE TABLE data 
(
    data_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    scenario_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES scenarios(scenario_id),
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories(category_id),
    id_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the temperature_values table
CREATE TABLE temperature_values 
(
    temperature_value_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES data(data_id),
    value FLOAT NOT NULL
);

-- Create the pressure_values table
CREATE TABLE pressure_values 
(
    pressure_value_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES data(data_id),
    value FLOAT NOT NULL
);

-- Create the etp_values table
CREATE TABLE etp_values 
(
    etp_value_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES data(data_id),
    value FLOAT NOT NULL
);

-- Create the outflow_values table
CREATE TABLE outflow_values 
(
    outflow_value_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES data(data_id),
    value FLOAT NOT NULL
);

Some comments on the table creation.
The IDs remain the same for all the data, for instance for Id_10 I can have different values in different files (temperature, outflow, etc.) the same is applicable to the dates, for a specific date I can have different type of data (temperature, outflow, etc.).
Now the question is how can I load my data into the tables in an efficient way, at this point I'm only interested in loading one file, only and only one .txt file let's say outflow into the outflow_values table. How am I supposed to do that?
PS: I'm not using pgAdmin, I'm working on Linux (debian based) and I using command line.

Have you read about parallel? Maybe it helps...

Try to use: COPY someTable FROM '/path/to/file/' …
More information here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html
How to skip the header you can see here: How to make Postgres Copy ignore first line of large txt file
P.S. You can also look at PGLoader.
